# Amsthm numbering depending on section depth

Tags: numbering, amsthm

I'm using `amsthm` and `thmtools` to define custom theorem environments, definition environments, etc. All such environments share the same counter.

Is it possible to vary the numbering format depending on the section depth? I want to achieve the following numbering format:

1 Section

1.1 Theorem

1.2 Definition

1.1 Subsection

1.1.1 Theorem

1.1.2 Lemma

Comment: What do you use *exactly* `thmtools` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix the theorem counter with a section-specific numbering scheme:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}% Reset theorem counter with every section
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsubsection}
\newcommand{\theoremprefix}{}
\let\thetheoremsaved\thetheorem
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\theoremprefix\thetheoremsaved}
\let\sectionsaved\section
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\par}{\renewcommand{\theoremprefix}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Th 1
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
Df 1
\end{definition}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{theorem}
Th 2
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
Lm 1
\end{lemma}
\section{Two}
\begin{theorem}
Th 3
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
Lm 2
\end{lemma}
\subsection{Other}
\begin{theorem}
Th 4
\end{theorem}
\subsection{Other 2}
\begin{definition}
Df 2
\end{definition}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @JoelCroteau: `\thetheorem` represents the theorem number, which I've changed to `\theoremprefix\thetheoremsaved` (adding `\theoremprefix`). Then, I update `\theoremprefix` with every call to a sectional unit using `\patchcmd`.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure if you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifsection
\newif\ifsubsection
\preto\section{\sectiontrue\subsectionfalse}
\preto\subsection{\sectionfalse\subsectiontrue}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}% <cmd>
  {\ignorespaces}% <search>
  {\ifsection
    \numberwithin{theorem}{section}
    \else
    \numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}
    \fi
    \setcounter{theorem}{0}\relax\ignorespaces}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Th 1
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
Df 1
\end{definition}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{theorem}
Th 2
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
Lm 1
\end{lemma}
\section{Two}
\begin{theorem}
Th 3
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
Lm 2
\end{lemma}
\subsection{Other}
\begin{theorem}
Th 4
\end{theorem}
\subsection{Other 2}
\begin{definition}
Df 2
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]