# Numbering theorem-like counters whitin each section, subsection and subsubsection independently

Tags: pdftex, numbering, amsmath, theorems, subsection

I'm trying to enumerate the different theorem-like counters within each sections independently. I'm using the code I found on [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199597/amsthm-numbering-depending-on-section-depth). However, theorems, lemmas, and definitions are not numbered in themselves, they are numbered consecutively.

My MWE is like that;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}% Reset theorem counter with every section
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsubsection}
\newcommand{\theoremprefix}{}
\let\thetheoremsaved\thetheorem
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\theoremprefix\thetheoremsaved}
\let\sectionsaved\section
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\par}{\renewcommand{\theoremprefix}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 1
    \end{definition}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 2
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 2
    \end{definition}
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 1
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 2
    \end{definition}

    \begin{lemma}
        Lm 1
    \end{lemma}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 2
    \end{theorem}

    \subsubsection{SubSubsection}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 1
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 2
    \end{definition}
    
    \begin{lemma}
        Lm 1
    \end{lemma}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 2
    \end{theorem}
    
    
    \section{Two}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{lemma}
        Lm 1
    \end{lemma}
    
    
\end{document}
```

and it looks like this.

[image: output of MWE]

How can I fix this numbering sequence?

Comment: The code you are using is only for `theorem`, you have to do the same with `definition` and `lemma`

Comment: Seems you don't want to use the `theorem` counter for `definition` and `lemma`. So you should remove the optional argument `[theorem]` from the definitions of `definition` and `lemma`.

Comment: Dear @cabobah your suggestion doesn't work as i want, when I removed the argument `[theorem]` from `definition` and `lemma`, the section and subsection numbers are also removed, and they do not appear next to the names. Morever, the explanations in the links you gave are not related to numbering.

Comment: Dear @DG when I add `\newcommand{\definitionprefix}{}
\let\thedefinitionsaved\thedefinition
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\definitionprefix\thedefinitionsaved}
\let\sectionsaved\section
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\par}{\renewcommand{\definitionprefix}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}}{}{}
` this code for `definition` before `makeatother`, nothing changed

Comment: Maybe share a link to the post where you got that code from?

Comment: It looks like you edited your question with the intention of reopening it.  Is that correct?  Could you explain why you'd like it reopened, given that you found an answer and the community thinks another question is also an answer?

Comment: Dear @Teepeemm, since I thought the title of the question asked was similar to the previous questions, I changed the title of the question and reposted it. Did I think wrong? Although the question type is similar to the previous questions, the answer given is not the same as the previous question answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself by applying @cabohah's suggestion correctly. Here is the MWE that works the way I want it to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}% Reset theorem counter with every section
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsubsection}

\@addtoreset{definition}{section}
\@addtoreset{definition}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{definition}{subsubsection}

\@addtoreset{lemma}{section}
\@addtoreset{lemma}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{lemma}{subsubsection}

\newcommand{\definitionprefix}{}
\let\thedefinitionsaved\thedefinition
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\definitionprefix\thedefinitionsaved}

\newcommand{\lemmaprefix}{}
\let\thelemmasaved\thelemma
\renewcommand{\thelemma}{\lemmaprefix\thelemmasaved}

\newcommand{\theoremprefix}{}
\let\thetheoremsaved\thetheorem
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\theoremprefix\thetheoremsaved}

\let\sectionsaved\section
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\par}{
    \renewcommand{\theoremprefix}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}
    \renewcommand{\definitionprefix}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}
    \renewcommand{\lemmaprefix}{\csname the#1\endcsname.}
    }{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 1
    \end{definition}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 2
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 2
    \end{definition}
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 1
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 2
    \end{definition}

    \begin{lemma}
        Lm 1
    \end{lemma}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 2
    \end{theorem}

    \subsubsection{SubSubsection}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 1
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}
        Df 2
    \end{definition}
    
    \begin{lemma}
        Lm 1
    \end{lemma}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 2
    \end{theorem}
    
    
    \section{Two}
    \begin{theorem}
        Th 1
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{lemma}
        Lm 1
    \end{lemma}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image: output of new MWE]